# AS3 Assign a Date which is in String format to a variable t:Date

Tags: actionscript-3

Writing in AS3. I cannot write:

```
t:Date = u.data.time;
```

`u.data.time` is `"Mon Oct 31 00:00:00 GMT-0500 2005"`,because this cannot convert to Date.
Can you guys suggest a way to assign this to a date?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use [Date.parse()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#parse%28%29), like so:

```
var t : Date = new Date( Date.parse(u.data.time) );
```

The static `Date.parse()` method returns, according to the documentation, "a number equaling the number of milliseconds elapsed since January 1, 1970, UTC", which incidentally is the same time format that the `Date()` constructor expects as it's first parameter, when no other parameters are given.

**EDIT:**
After OP stating that the above code doesn't work, I have tried the following example, which works fine for me:

```
var str : String = 'Mon Oct 31 00:00:00 GMT-0500 2005';

var t : Number = Date.parse(str);
var d : Date = new Date(t);

trace(t); // Outputs: 1130734800000
trace(d.toString()); // Outputs: Mon Oct 31 06:00:00 GMT+0100 2005
```

Although it's printed in my local timezone, the `Date` instance `d` seems to include the correct date/time data.

Comment: Giving me "Invalid Date" as result(trace(t)).
trace(t1+u.data.time+Date.parse(u.data.time));

Invalid Date 2008-10-30 16:48:59 UTC NaN

Comment: What is the output of trace(u.data.time)? If it follows the format from your original post, Date.parse() should return a number. See the documentation. If it doesn't, can you please post the output of trace(u.data.time)? I'm editing my post to add some sample code that works fine for me.

Comment: I know it is a bit too late... but I am having the same trouble with UTC sttrings. The string is in UTC format and not GMT format, i think flex is not yet capable of dealing with UTC strings... I hope I am wrong!